# SwitchCompat animation breaks if another view is updated at the same time

Tags: android, android-animation, switchcompat

I'm trying to update a `TextView` (let's call it `name`) from the `SwitchCompat`'s `OnCheckedChanged()` method. The problem is that right after I call `name.setText()`, the animation that moves SwitchCompat's thumb button interrupts and the thumb button just hops to another side. Here's the sample:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    name.setText("Some name");
}
```

I also tried to use `Handler` to post my updates and it turns out that if I post before the animation is done, it will still be interrupted. For example, if the animation takes `1000 ms` and I call `postDelayed()` with the delay of `500 ms`, the thumb button smoothly moves to the middle of the `SwitchCompat` and then just hops. Code:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            name.setText("Some name");
        }
    }, 500);
```

Both views are the parts of a single layout (which represents a `ListView` item):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="0">

        <TableRow>
            <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/isAlarmOn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainPanel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So how do I change that `TextView` without breaking the animation?

Comment: If your activity is a descendant of `AppCompatActivity`, have you tried to use `Switch` directly, not `SwitchCompat`?

Comment: Nope, you think it would make any difference? @azizbekian

Comment: Give it a try .

Comment: The problem is that `Switch` looks different from `SwitchCompat` on pre-lollipop devices, and I kinda need them to look the same. @azizbekian

Comment: If your activity is descendant of `AppCompatActivity`, `Spinner` would be substituted with appcompat version of it.

Comment: I just tried to replace it with `Switch` and it doesn't animate either. As far as I know `Switch` is not supposed to be animated (on pre-lollipop devices at least, and I run it on KitKat).

Comment: Also tried to inherit `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`, no luck either. @azizbekian

Comment: Do you have a text change listener set on that `TextView`?

Comment: No, no listeners there

Comment: I just noticed that sometimes the animation doesn't break, for example it almost always works for the first item in the list, but if add another one it won't be animated. Must be something with the adapter

Comment: Use systrace tool, you'll be able to find out what operations happen during animation. Most possibly you are skipping some frames.

Comment: Sure, thanks for advice